# SQL - Conditional average

Tags: mysql, sql, average, aggregate-functions

So i have a query like so in MySQL;

```
  select Schedule.trackName, Ratings.rating, count(trackName)
from Ratings 
inner Join Schedule on Ratings.trackNo = Schedule.trackNo 
Where rating > 2
group by 1
having count(trackName) > 1;
```

If i wanted to take the average of the ratings output from this query, how would i implement that

Comment: `SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ...... `   ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate `AVG` function to achieve that:

> Returns the average value of expr

Here is your code with `AVG` in to return the average and count, grouped by the `trackName` column:

```
SELECT  Schedule.trackName,
        AVG(Ratings.rating),
        COUNT(trackName)
  FROM  Ratings 
    INNER JOIN Schedule ON Ratings.trackNo = Schedule.trackNo 
  WHERE rating > 2
  GROUP BY Schedule.trackName
  HAVING COUNT(trackName) > 1;
```

Incidentally, it's better to use the column names in `GROUP BY` clauses rather than numbers.  That little trick doesn't work on other RDBMS.

More information about `AVG` can be seen in the official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg).

Comment: @SOMESOME You're welcome. Please remember to mark the answer when you can